# Opening an image file into WritableBitmap

Tags: c#, silverlight, writeablebitmap

Here is the problem.
I want to open a file from local drives, then make it into a WritableBitmap so i can edit it.
But the problem is, i cannot create a WritableBitmap from Uri or something like that. Also i know how to open a file into BitmapImage but i cannot figure out how to open a file as WritableBitmap.
Is there way to open a file directly into a WritableBitmap,if there is not, is there a way to convert a BitmapImage to a WritableBitmap?
Thanks guys.

Comment: it seems that we can pass a bitmap directly into writablebitmaps constructor. My VS gave me errors while i first tried it but it seems working now. It wasn't a good question at all, sorry guys.

Comment: It will work, but it will be resized if above some mega pixels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load your image file into a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) and use that as a source for your [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx):

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("YourImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Actually, in Siverlight, it gives me exception.  So it's not a solution

Comment: @Peter, which exception do you receive?

Comment: `BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("header.png", UriKind.Relative)); WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bi);` The 2nd line `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @Peter, did you check that `bi` is not `null` after the call to the `BitmapImage` constructor? If it is, it would be quite logical for the `WriteableBitmap` constructor to fail.

Comment: Yes, I did check. See my answer.  Would you mind test my code on your machine?

Comment: Loading a WriteableBitmap from a BitmapImage is actually a workaround as the final image is scaled to physical device limitations. Thus, a 5MP can be rescaled to a 1MP image. Not useful, considering WriteableBitmap is used for image processing.

Comment: @Peter Lee. What do you get when using CreateOptions set to None?

Comment: @LéonPelletier  i set creation option to None, Error exist (Silverlight 5). In created bitmap image source PixelHeight and PixelWidth is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert and don't have immediate access to intellisense and whatnot, but here goes...

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(stream);
var writeableBitmap = new WritableBitmap(bitmap);
```

Even if not a perfect example this should be enough to point you in the right direction. Hope so.

Comment: you cannot pass a bitmap directly into a writablebitmap

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);` not allowed in Silverlight, unless in OpenFileDialog

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 5 you can use below method to open file from local disk and convert it to BitmapImage and make it in to WriteableBitmap;

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = false;


        dlg.ShowDialog();
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { };
        if (dlg.File == null) return;
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
       // bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\saw\Desktop\image.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        bi.SetSource(dlg.File.OpenRead());
        WriteableBitmap eb=new WriteableBitmap(bi);
```

setting new Uri gave me error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) while trying to create WriteableBitmap