# How to create WriteableBitmap from BitmapImage?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, writeablebitmap

I could create WriteableBitmap from pictures in Assets.

```
Uri imageUri1 = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/sample1.jpg");
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = await new WriteableBitmap(1, 1).FromContent(imageUri1);
```

but, I can't create WriteableBitmap from Pictures Directory,(I'm using  [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/))

```
//open image
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFile file = await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync("sample2.jpg");
var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

//create bitmap
BitmapImage bitmap2 = new BitmapImage();
bitmap2.SetSource();
bitmap2.SetSource(stream);

//create WriteableBitmap, but cannot
WriteableBitmap writeableBmp3 = 
    await WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.FromBitmapImage(bitmap2);
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a total contrivance, but it does seem to work ...

```
// load a jpeg, be sure to have the Pictures Library capability in your manifest
var folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("test.jpg");
var data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

// create a stream from the file
var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
var dw = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(ms);
dw.WriteBuffer(data);
await dw.StoreAsync();
ms.Seek(0);

// find out how big the image is, don't need this if you already know
var bm = new BitmapImage();
await bm.SetSourceAsync(ms);

// create a writable bitmap of the right size
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bm.PixelWidth, bm.PixelHeight);
ms.Seek(0);

// load the writable bitpamp from the stream
await wb.SetSourceAsync(ms);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the way reading an image to a WriteableBitmap works as Filip noted:

```
StorageFile imageFile = ...

WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = null;
using (IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await imageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
   BitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(
      imageStream);

   BitmapTransform dummyTransform = new BitmapTransform();
   PixelDataProvider pixelDataProvider =
      await bitmapDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 
      BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, dummyTransform, 
      ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
      ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
   byte[] pixelData = pixelDataProvider.DetachPixelData();

   writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
      (int)bitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelWidth,
      (int)bitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelHeight);
   using (Stream pixelStream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
   {
      await pixelStream.WriteAsync(pixelData, 0, pixelData.Length);
   }
}
```

Note that I am using the pixel format and alpha mode Writeable Bitmap uses and that I pass  .

Answer (score 3):

`WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.FromBitmapImage()` works by using the original Uri used to load `BitmapImage` and IIRC it only works with `BitmapImage`s from the appx. In your case there isn't even a Uri since loading from Pictures folder can only be done by loading from stream, so your options from the fastest to slowest (I think) are:

1. Open the image as `WriteableBitmap` from the get go, so that you don't need to reopen it or copy bits around.
2. If you need to have two copies - open it as `WriteableBitmap` and then create a new `WriteableBitmap` of same size and copy the pixel buffer.
3. If you need to have two copies - track the path used to open the first bitmap and then create a new `WriteableBitmap` by loading it from the same file as the original one.

I think option 2 might be faster than option 3 since you avoid decoding a compressed image twice.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but how to open image as writeablebitmap from the get go,? I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254225/opening-an-image-file-into-writablebitmap) may be helpful, but I cant't  cannot pass a bitmap directly into a writablebitmap .

Comment: No that link is for Silverlight. You need to get a StorageFile for your image e.g. using a file picker, then await OpenReadAsync, then create a 1x1 WriteableBitmap and await SetSourceAsync. Check this for sample/extensions: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4d568d4e4c6a#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapLoadExtensions.cs