# Convert BitmapImage to WritableBitmap Windows phone 8.1 RT(runtime)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, bitmapimage, writablebitmap

I need to gray scale a image before it gets displayed. Image is coming from server. I used *BitmapImage* as a `Source` of Image. I am able to show image using *BitmapImage*.

Now I need to grayscale image, for that I found that WritableBitmap can be used to convert it to grayscale. I used **WritableBitmapEx.WinRT** library for gray scale.

but the issue is I am not able to convert **BitmapImage to WritableBitmap** in WinRT.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/14722571/3397793

Comment: Seen that! its getting stream from file

Answer (score 0):

Use a WriteableBitmap instead of the BitmapImage to begin with. Other than access to the PixelBuffer they can be used almost identically.

You can't directly extract the pixels from a BitmapImage. All of the reasonable methods to "convert" a BitmapImage to a WritableBitmap get the data from the original source. If you can't get the original UriSource (since you loaded from stream) and don't have the stream available to reload from you're out of luck.

The only other (ugly) option is to snapshot the Image with RenderTargetBitmap

Comment: I have used WritableBitmap directly as binding of image's source. Earlier it was binded to url of image. I am getting urls in web service response and they are too many. If I directly use WritableBitmap then I need to create WritableBitmap in webservice itself so that it will get displayed when done as property of type WritableBitmap is directly binded to image src. This needed to done on UI thread. But its taking time to create random stream from url and then opening that stream to create WritableBitmap. Here I need to wrap this for around 20 to 30 images, which need to show at a same time.