# UWP Apply Colorfilter to BitmapImage

Tags: uwp, tint, colorfilter

How can I easly apply a ColorFilter to a Bitmap, Image, whatsoever. On Android this is a one-liner: `myDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, Mode.SRC_IN);`
For Windows I only found giant over the top compilcated samples to manipulate images in every way. That is way too much for my needs. I don't want to manipulate every pixel at once or similar, I just have a Image with a white Icon and i want that to become green or else programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Composition APIs do do this fairly easily to any visual - you can see code for this here https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/blob/master/Demos/EffectEditor/MainPage.xaml.cs (see tint / hue effects)

Answer (score 0):

After much time spent wandering around MSDN and S/O, I pieced together the following class.  It doesn't use WriteableBitmapEx or any library beyond what is already provided by Microsoft.

There is technically only one blend mode available with this answer; SRC_ATOP.  This will iterate over each pixel and replace the colour value with the specified tint colour if the pixel is not transparent (alpha 0).

As noted in many of the answers I've seen; this will be quite slow and not recommended for anything other than applying a one-time tint (i.e. on start-up of your app).  If the colour will not be changing frequently, you may wish to save the result to a local file rather than apply the tint each time.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class ImageManipulationHelper
    {

        public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> ApplyTint(Uri sourceUri, Color tintColour)
        {
            WriteableBitmap source = await GetImageFile(sourceUri);
            byte[] byteArray = null;
            using (Stream stream = source.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                long streamLength = stream.Length;
                byteArray = new byte[streamLength];
                await stream.ReadAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                if (streamLength > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < streamLength; i += 4)
                    {
                        // check the pixel is not transparent (BGRA)
                        if (byteArray[i + 3] != 0)
                        {
                            byteArray[i] = tintColour.B; // Blue
                            byteArray[i + 1] = tintColour.G;  // Green
                            byteArray[i + 2] = tintColour.R; // Red
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
            if (byteArray != null)
            {
                WriteableBitmap destination = await PixelBufferToWriteableBitmap(byteArray, source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight);
                return destination;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static async Task<WriteableBitmap> GetImageFile(Uri fileUri)
        {
            StorageFile imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileUri);

            WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = null;
            using (IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await imageFile.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                BitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);

                BitmapTransform dummyTransform = new BitmapTransform();
                PixelDataProvider pixelDataProvider =
                   await bitmapDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                   BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, dummyTransform,
                   ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
                   ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
                byte[] pixelData = pixelDataProvider.DetachPixelData();

                writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
                   (int)bitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelWidth,
                   (int)bitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelHeight);
                using (Stream pixelStream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
                {
                    await pixelStream.WriteAsync(pixelData, 0, pixelData.Length);
                }
            }

            return writeableBitmap;
        }



        public static async Task PixelBufferToWriteableBitmap(WriteableBitmap wb, byte[] bgra)
        {
            using (Stream stream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(bgra, 0, bgra.Length);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> PixelBufferToWriteableBitmap(byte[] bgra, int width, int height)
        {
            var wb = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
            await PixelBufferToWriteableBitmap(wb, bgra);
            return wb;
        }

    }
}
```

Happy Coding ^_^

References:

[WriteableBitmap to byte array](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/a9365644-bde1-4995-8b35-bcb31a866096/uwp-writeablebitmap-to-byte-array-then-byte-array-to-writeablebitmap?forum=wpdevelop)

[Set a pixel in WriteableBitmap](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ae75c899-21a8-4800-9707-38563fcbbb2a/uwpset-a-pixel-in-writeablebitmap-in-windows-10-universal?forum=wpdevelop)

[How to create WriteableBitmap from BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718855/how-to-create-writeablebitmap-from-bitmapimage)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a direct answer because you asked about a more general case of `BitmapImage`, it's still worth noting that many times you need such a coloring with icons. If you are actually using a `BitmapIcon`, you are free to change its `Foreground` and you'll get that same support you found in Android.